# Get labels from check boxes in form

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form that has some fields: a textarea, a text box and stochastic number of checkbox that varies depending on the product. I want to know how I can get the label of the check boxes that are checked.

This is my form:

```
<form class="form-inline">
<strong><h3>Revise este produto</h3></strong><br>

{% for tag in tags %}
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value=""> #Ótimo
</label>
{% endfor %}

<br/>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<label>Envie outras hashtags</label> <br/>
<input type="text" class="span3" placeholder="exemplo1, exemplo2">
<br />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<label>Deixe sua opinião (opcional)</label> <br/>
<textarea name="Text1" cols="80" class="span3" rows="5" placeholder="Digite sua opinião aqui"></textarea>
<br/>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><h4>Pronto!</h4></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In models.py:

```
class Tag:
    published = BooleanField()
    (...)
```

In the template:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="" {% if tag.published %}checked{% endif %}> #Ótimo
</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Assuming you are sending the form as a POST, the values of the
  selected checkboxes are in `request.POST.getlist('tag')`.

  Note that only checked boxes are ever sent in the POST, but the list
  contains the value elements of all the boxes that are checked.

For example :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="4" />
```

Say if 1,4 were checked,

```
check_values = request.POST.getlist('checks')
```

check_values will contain [1,4] (those values that were checked)